# jQuery Calculationswith Decimal

Tags: jquery

So i am unsure how to display decimal from these calculations - i also need to show interest code is:

```
function reCalc(borrowValue) {
    $("#targetVal").html("&pound;" + borrowValue);
    var borrowBC = Math.floor(borrowValue * 1.25);
    var borrowAC = Math.floor(borrowBC + 4.95);
    $("#paybackAmount").html(borrowAC);
}
```

Which works like:

```
borrowValue = 100
BorrowBC = 125
BorrowAC = 129
```

2 things i want to ideally do:

1) Be decimal for the BorrowAC so its 129.95 not 129

2) i would also like to show the difference to work out interest applied so assuming borrowValue minus borrowAC i think?

Basically if i borrow 100 i pay 25 interest and 4.95 charges so i want to show the charges and interest applied to the 100 separately this will increase based on the amount they want though

Much appreciated in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then edit like this

```
var borrowBC = borrowValue * 1.25;
var borrowAC = borrowBC + 4.95;
```

For your second,it will be

```
var interest = (borrowAC - borrowValue).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: I don't understand, is that more or less what i already have?

Comment: Super that worked, so simple heh any ideas on how question 2?

Comment: just done it, but was var borrowJC = (borrowAC - borrowValue).toFixed(2);

Comment: Sry i didnt noticed that borrowAC > borrowVlaue,anyway thanku too

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript toFixed() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)

```
var borrowBC = (borrowValue * 1.25).toFixed(2);
var borrowAC = (borrowBC + 4.95).toFixed(2);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dvuqV/)

Comment: TypeError: (borrowBC + 4.95).toFixed is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

var borrowAC = (borrowBC + 4.95).toFixed(2);